# How to open chrome new tab in pyautogui. i am not getting any error but code is not working

Tags: python, automation, pyautogui

I Am Saving Whatsapp Contacts to sheets.google.com. I am using the `new_tab = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('btn.png')` and pyautogui.click(new_tab) To open a new tab. but its not clicking to that button i dont get any error how to fix!!

My Code:

```
import pyautogui    

new_tab = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('btn.png')
pyautogui.click(new_tab)
```

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `artificial-intelligence` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: @desertnaut I am Sorry Sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
new_tab= pyautogui.locateOnScreen('btn.png', confidence=.6)
        pyautogui.moveTo(new_tab[0], new_tab[1], duration=self.speed)
        pyautogui.click(interval=self.click_speed)
```

could be work